# How to request merchanID from binance to use its API create order

Tags: binance, binance-api-client

may i know how to get merchantId or whats the process to request merchantId from binance ?
https://developers.binance.com/docs/binance-pay/api-order-create

thanks in advance.

cheers
Miguel

Answer (score 1):

The `POST /binancepay/openapi/order` endpoint that you're referencing, creates a [P2P merchant](https://www.binance.com/en/support/announcement/360039019631) order. You can get the ID in your Merchant profile of the [P2P platform](https://p2p.binance.com/en) (after Binance has confirmed you as a P2P merchant).

If this is not what you're looking for and you just want to submit a (regular) spot order (e.g. to buy BTC to USDT), you can use the [POST /api/v3/order](https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md#new-order--trade) endpoint. It only requires your API key and API secret that you can generate in the [API management](https://www.binance.com/en/my/settings/api-management) section of your profile.